# How can i set border of cities on svg interactive maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm working on Interactive SVG Maps of Turkey. There are 81 cities (they are created with `<g>` elements) and their districts (they are created with `<g>` child elements). A city borders occur their districts' border. You can see code below:

```
<g id="Hakkari" transform="translate(4607.000000, 1335.000000)" data-transform-left="-521.5" data-transform-top="-87">
                    <g id="Merkez" transform="translate(10.000000, 2.000000)">
                        <polygon id="Shape" stroke="#FFFFFF" fill="#9FB4B7" fill-rule="nonzero" points="31 59 119 38 181 0 193 43 155 64 163 167 49 175 0 142"></polygon>
                        <g id="MER" transform="translate(85.000000, 98.000000)" font-size="6" font-family="Helvetica-Bold, Helvetica" fill="#000000" font-weight="bold">
                            <text>
                                <tspan x="0" y="6">MER</tspan>
                            </text>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g id="Yüksekova" transform="translate(165.000000, 0.000000)">
                        <polygon id="Shape" stroke="#FFFFFF" fill="#9FB4B7" fill-rule="nonzero" points="38 44 122 0 163 7 185 27 185 107 118 133 79 177 38 176 25 190 7 168 0 66"></polygon>
                        <g id="YÜK" transform="translate(78.000000, 86.000000)" font-size="6" font-family="Helvetica-Bold, Helvetica" fill="#000000" font-weight="bold">
                            <text>
                                <tspan x="0" y="6">YÜK</tspan>
                            </text>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g id="Şemdinli" transform="translate(244.000000, 107.000000)">
                        <polygon id="Shape" stroke="#FFFFFF" fill="#9FB4B7" fill-rule="nonzero" points="106 0 168 47 172 104 121 94 40 169 14 127 31 87 0 70 39 26"></polygon>
                        <g id="ŞEM" transform="translate(81.000000, 62.000000)" font-size="6" font-family="Helvetica-Bold, Helvetica" fill="#000000" font-weight="bold">
                            <text>
                                <tspan x="0" y="6">ŞEM</tspan>
                            </text>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g id="Çukurca" transform="translate(0.000000, 143.000000)">
                        <polygon id="Shape" stroke="#FFFFFF" fill="#9FB4B7" fill-rule="nonzero" points="190 47 163 76 70 72 20 51 0 24 10 0 58 33 173 26"></polygon>
                        <g id="ÇUK" transform="translate(104.000000, 50.000000)" font-size="6" font-family="Helvetica-Bold, Helvetica" fill="#000000" font-weight="bold">
                            <text>
                                <tspan x="0" y="6">ÇUK</tspan>
                            </text>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
```

I want to set thick and black outer city borders, not districts. You can see

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure what you are asking since I'm not acquainted with the geography of your country.

There are a few mistakes in your SVG: you are using the same `id` several times, so I've changed it to a class. Also your SVG is extremely verbose, So I've moved some of the styles to css.

Supposing that you want to outline the 4 polygons, I've used an SVG filter to draw the red line: `<g id="Hakkari" filter="url(#outline-red)" . . . .`

I hope this is what you are asking for.

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.Shape {
  stroke: #ffffff;
  fill: #9fb4b7;
}
text {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Helvetica-Bold, Helvetica;
  fill: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#Hakkari{filter:url(#outline-red); }
/*#Hakkari:hover{filter:url(#outline-red); }*/
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "4570 1300 500 350">
  <defs>
    <filter id="outline-red">
    <feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" result="expanded" operator="dilate" radius="3"/>
    <feFlood flood-color="red" result="red" />
    <feComposite in ="red" in2="expanded" operator="in" />
    <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
    
  </defs>
  <g id="Hakkari"  transform="translate(4607.000000, 1335.000000)" data-transform-left="-521.5" data-transform-top="-87">
                    <g id="Merkez" transform="translate(10.000000, 2.000000)">
                        <polygon class="Shape" points="31 59 119 38 181 0 193 43 155 64 163 167 49 175 0 142"></polygon>
                        <g id="MER" transform="translate(85.000000, 98.000000)" >
                            <text>
                                <tspan x="0" y="6">MER</tspan>
                            </text>
                        </g>
                    </g>
    
    
                    <g id="Yüksekova" transform="translate(165.000000, 0.000000)">
                        <polygon class="Shape"  points="38 44 122 0 163 7 185 27 185 107 118 133 79 177 38 176 25 190 7 168 0 66"></polygon>
                        <g id="YÜK" transform="translate(78.000000, 86.000000)" >
                            <text>
                                <tspan x="0" y="6">YÜK</tspan>
                            </text>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g id="Şemdinli" transform="translate(244.000000, 107.000000)">
                        <polygon class="Shape"  points="106 0 168 47 172 104 121 94 40 169 14 127 31 87 0 70 39 26"></polygon>
                        <g id="ŞEM" transform="translate(81.000000, 62.000000)" >
                            <text>
                                <tspan x="0" y="6">ŞEM</tspan>
                            </text>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g id="Çukurca" transform="translate(0.000000, 143.000000)">
                        <polygon class="Shape"  points="190 47 163 76 70 72 20 51 0 24 10 0 58 33 173 26"></polygon>
                        <g id="ÇUK" transform="translate(104.000000, 50.000000)" >
                            <text>
                                <tspan x="0" y="6">ÇUK</tspan>
                            </text>
                        </g>
                    </g>
  </g>
  
</svg>
```

UPDATE:

This is an other way of adding a border to a group of elements:
I'm using the group as a background with a border.
then I'm using the same group as intend.

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
}

#A {
  fill: red;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 10px;
}

#B {
  stroke: #ffffff;
  fill: #9fb4b7;
}
text {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Helvetica-Bold, Helvetica;
  fill: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
  stroke: none;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="4570 1300 500 350" width="500" height="350">
  <defs>
    <g id="Hakkari">
                    <g id="Merkez" transform="translate(10.000000, 2.000000)">
                        <polygon class="Shape" points="31 59 119 38 181 0 193 43 155 64 163 167 49 175 0 142"></polygon>
                        
                    </g>
    
    
                    <g id="Yüksekova" transform="translate(165.000000, 0.000000)">
                        <polygon class="Shape"  points="38 44 122 0 163 7 185 27 185 107 118 133 79 177 38 176 25 190 7 168 0 66"></polygon>
                        
                    </g>
                    <g id="Şemdinli" transform="translate(244.000000, 107.000000)">
                        <polygon class="Shape"  points="106 0 168 47 172 104 121 94 40 169 14 127 31 87 0 70 39 26"></polygon>
                        
                    </g>
                    <g id="Çukurca" transform="translate(0.000000, 143.000000)">
                        <polygon class="Shape"  points="190 47 163 76 70 72 20 51 0 24 10 0 58 33 173 26"></polygon>
                        
                    </g>
  </g>  
  </defs>
  
<g transform="translate(4607.000000, 1335.000000)" data-transform-left="-521.5" data-transform-top="-87"> 
  <use id="A" xlink:href="#Hakkari" />
  <use id="B" xlink:href="#Hakkari"  />
  
  <g id="Hakkari_text">
    <g id="MER" transform="translate(85.000000, 98.000000)" >
                            <text>
                                <tspan x="0" y="6">MER</tspan>
                            </text>
                        </g>
    <g id="YÜK" transform="translate(243.000000, 86.000000)" >
                            <text>
                                <tspan x="0" y="6">YÜK</tspan>
                            </text>
                        </g>
    <g id="ŞEM" transform="translate(325.000000, 169.000000)" >
                            <text>
                                <tspan x="0" y="6">ŞEM</tspan>
                            </text>
                        </g>
    <g id="ÇUK" transform="translate(104.000000, 193.000000)">
                            <text>
                                <tspan x="0" y="6">ÇUK</tspan>
                            </text>
                        </g>
  </g>

  </g>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. your code is working, but there is still a problem when the pointer comes on the city, it turns "red". I only want the border to be red not the whole city.

Comment: Also, in the example, i can't see borders normal view. Only click a city, map was zoomed than i saw borders. how can i add borders in normal view and zoom view?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand you. I think Hakkari is a city. The border of Hakkary is red.  I've updated the code. Now the border of Hakkary is red only on hover.

Comment: I'm afraid because i can't tell what i want. Hakkari is a city and I want to see Hakkari's red border when i was looking the map with non-zoom (normal view). I can see red border of Hakkari when I zoom with your first code. But i can not see in non-zoom.

Comment: The other little problem is hover effect. Your code is filling red, but i want to only set borders with red not inner.

Comment: Thinks I don't understand; 1. You say the code is filling red. No, it's not. I've checked it in IE, Edge, Chrome, Firefox, Safari. 2. What do you mean by zoom? I've added an other way of adding a border to the group. I don't think you will like it but I try

Comment: Is there a place that we can talk ?

Comment: hello, can you write the code content according to my code?